# Need Value generated from Javascript inserted into hidden form field

Tags: javascript

I am using a geo location script that generates the users city based on IP.

Header Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Code that generates the city:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="script.php">Email: <input       size="35" type="text" name="email"> 
<input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="" >
    </form>
```

I need to be able to insert the value generated from the javascript into the value field of the form.

I cant seem to do it, ive tried various ways like placing this after the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("city").value = "1";
alert(document.getElementById("city").value);
</script>
```

This is on a page that has been saved as .php.

Comment: Assuming the last code snippet is example code: Does the browser console give you any warnings or other messanges? And are you sure that the code is executed at a time where you can actually interact with the dom?

Answer (score 0):

You're just inserting "1". Try:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 var city = geoip_city();
document.write(city);
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("city").value = city;
alert(document.getElementById("city").value);
</script>
```

This may need refinement - I haven't used this library. The variable `city` allpws you to read the location twice.

Answer (score 0):

That company seems to [no longer support that version of the js library](http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js). Here's how you'd do it using their [latest lib](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/)

```js
"use strict";

var getCity = function( geoipResponse ){
    var cityName = geoipResponse.city.names.en || 'your city';
    document.getElementById('city').value = cityName;
    alert(cityName);
};

var fail = function(err) {
    alert(err.error);
    console.error(err);
}
geoip2.city( getCity, fail );
```

```html
<script src="http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="script.php">
    Email: <input size="35" type="text" name="email" /> 
    City:  <input type="not_hidden" id="city" name="city" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the statement as

```
document.form1.city.value="new value";
```

this would work